# Does reviewing suggested edits improve my profile standing on SO?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

Apparently I can now review edits made by users on questions.

Does approving/improving/rejecting edits influence my profile standing in any way?

If so, how does each respective action change my profile standing?

Comment: What do you mean by "standing"? There are reputation and badges...

Comment: If you get a lot of questions voted for deletion or to be closed, eventually you're not going to be allowed to ask questions anymore because your profile's "standing" will have fallen to a point where SO no longer believes that your contributions are, so to speak, in line with the standards of the community. Answering questions and asking questions that receive positive votes, raises your "standing", however... As I understand it

Comment: @Ortund Wouldn't the best thing then be to improve your question quality?

Comment: @Magisch Let's assume a hypothetical user who makes very good posts, but very bad reviews. It wouldn't make sense to tell this hypothetical reviewer to "post better content".

Comment: @S.L.Barth that would be the opposite of what OP is asking here. He is afraid that he will get Q banned because of his numerous LQ questions and wants to know if SE reviewing can prevent that.

Comment: @Magisch actually I want to know if LQ edit approval can get me banned

Comment: @Ortund review banned, yes, but not question banned. Thats an entirely different thing.

Comment: @Ortund - You have 234 questions, many of which are highly upvoted. I don't think you're anywhere near the point where you need to be worried about being banned from asking questions. Even if you were, you'd get clear warnings well in advance of this. Reviews, flags, and other moderation tasks you perform do nothing to impact this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not likely to get a post-ban for reviewing.

You can, however, get suspended from reviewing. The review queues have audits, known false positives / false negatives. When you review an audit wrongly (a.k.a. failing the audit), the system will remember this. After a number of failures, the review privilege will be temporarily suspended.

It is also possible to get a manual review suspension from a diamond moderator. This happens if the moderator catches you reviewing badly.

Review suspensions will not influence your reputation points or your "standing" with respect to the questions and answers that you post.

So, review with care. When in doubt, use <kbd>Skip</kbd>.